# Proving that a system of equalities and inequalities is inconsistent

Tags: inequality

Prove that the system

$a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i>0$

$ae+ai−bd+ei−fh=0$

$aei−hfa-bdi−gbf=0$

is inconsistent.

I tried using some standard techniques such as factoring, or multiplying an equality and  adding it to the other, but nothing seem to work.

(This problem arose from the study of sign pattern matrices.)

Comment: I already added the detail of where the problem came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the third equation, you know that $aei=hfa+bdi+gbf$. Now set $x=bdi+gbf$. Therefore,
$$aei=hfa+x$$$$ei=hf+\frac{x}{a}$$$$ei>hf$$
The same technique can be used to find that
$$ae>bd$$
Now set $y=ei-hf$ and $z=ae-bd$. These are both clearly positive. Now, rewriting the second equation using these variables, we get
$$ai+y+z=0$$
Since all three terms on the left are greater than $1$, this cannot be true.

Comment: Very informative! Thank you. What was your thinking process when you manipulated the expressions the way you did? I am asking because I still have to prove several similar statements.

Comment: @MarkLao The general process is to look for similarities between the two parts and then look for ways to relate them, and then reconstruct the more complex equation in terms of the simpler equation. In this case, I noticed mostly by chance that the positive elements from the second equation could be deconstructed from the positive term in the third equation. Other people might have a more all-encompassing strategy, but I mostly just go case-by-case. Sorry if that didn't help much.